# Properly re-trigerring function after state changed (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

(React/JS newbie here!)

Hi,

I have a component which is rendering some data regarding reports. One of the field is when report was executed. In my API - i have a foreign key there so value rendered on page is id number. As i was not able to trigger string representation from API - i decided that i will make some kind of mapping on frontend side. Idea is to use "getKey" function in the component to show this string representation:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ReportElement = ({ report, setReportUpdated, reportingPeriods }) => {
  const getKey = (object, value) => {
    return Object.keys(object).find((key) => object[key] === value);
  };


  const reportForUpdated = () => {
    setReportUpdated(report);
    console.log(report);
  };

  return (
    <tr key={report.id}>
      <td>{report.report}</td>
      <td>{report.reporting_period}</td>
      <td>{report.executed}</td>
      <td>{getKey(reportingPeriods,report.executed_on)}</td>
      <td>{report.on_time}</td>
      <td>{report.issues}</td>
      <td> {report.issues_description}</td>
      <td>
        <button className="update-status" onClick={reportForUpdated}>
          UPDATE STATUS
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

export default ReportElement;
```

Problem that i encountered is the fact that mapping works only when data is fetched from API. Once i have  state changed on report - i am ending up with empty `<td>` when all other elements are updated accordingly to the changed state. I have to fetch data again to have proper value shown (like "Business Day 13" which is mapped to id=13).

Any idea on how to trigger this function in a proper way (so that it renders appropriate value after state change) would be highly appreciated.

Banging my head against a wall for a couple of days and decided to ask Stack Overflow community.

Cheers!

EDIT:

1. Object that i am passing getKey function looks like this (once logged in consol):

```
{"": ""
BD 1 April 2021: 46
BD 2 April 2021: 47
BD 3 April 2021: 48
BD 4 April 2021: 49
BD 5 April 2021: 50
BD 6 April 2021: 51
BD 7 April 2021: 52
BD 8 April 2021: 53
BD 9 April 2021: 54
}
```

2. And I am passing prop to the function which has some attributes and one of them is id. State of "report" is changed in different component which is updating state of all reports:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// creating a component by declaring a function and passing inside all relevant props for updating the statuses
const Update = ({
  reportUpdated,
  setReportUpdated,
  setReports,
  reports,
  reportingPeriods,
}) => {

  const selection = ["", "YES", "NO"];

  const updateDatabase = async (id) => {
    console.log(reportUpdated);

    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/report_tracker/status-update/${id}`,
    content-type
   POST
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(reportUpdated),
      }
    );

    setReports(
      reports.map((report) => (report.id === id ? reportUpdated : report))
    );

    setReportUpdated([]);
  };
```

EDIT 2:

Example - i am getting 50 as report.executed_on from an API.

so in line with below code:

```
<td>{getKey(reportingPeriods,report.executed_on)}</td>
```

I would like to get "BD 5 April 2021" from a "mapping" I created in getKey function.

At this moment - all rows of my table are pulling correct strings (so BD 5, BD 6, etc.) but when one of them is updated (for example i change report.executed_on to 55) - all data in ReportElement component are as they are in State but this td tag is ending up empty. I have to fetch the data again to see the change happened (Python backend is updated and is showing already 55 so post method seems to be working. The same is with the component as i see in developer tools that state was updated to 55 but that's not visible till i trigger fetching data to show from backend one more time).

Comment: The component in your code snippet has no state nor does it map any data. Have you included all relevant code in your question?

Comment: Thank you for indicating that something could be missing, @Drew Reese. Not sure if additional comments will help but i added an "EDIT" section to my question.

Comment: What function do you want to trigger after a state update, and what state/value update do you want to trigger it? Your question/issue is still quite unclear.

Comment: Added EDIT 2 with explanation of what i would like to see, @Drew Reese.

Answer (score 0):

Use useEffect to fetch data in a functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(yourProp)
}, [yourProp])
```

That way the useEffect will watch for any changes in the yourProp props. Using an empty array(in useEffect) means that the useEffect will only trigger in the first render of the functional component. Meaning that it will not be triggered in any of the props change.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, Martin. I checked what console is logging and state seems to be changed. Unfortunately - my getKey function is not being trigger properly with re-rendering of a component and i am ending up with empty value instead of updated state. Myabe the way i wrote the function (or initiate it) is wrong. I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem i had.

There was a change needed in setReports for state changing

Initially it was:

```
 setReports(
      reports.map((report) => (report.id === id ? reportUpdated : report))
    );
```

It was updating value only where id for element being changed was found.

Now i have it as follows:

```
setReports(
      reports.map((report) =>
        report.id === id
          ? {
              ...reportUpdated,
              executed_on: parseInt(reportUpdated.executed_on),
            }
          : report
      )
    );
```

I used spread operator to see the update and noticed that i was getting a string instead of an integer for "executed_on" attribute which was not matching my ids being integers. Corrected that by using parseInt and now - works like a charm.

Maybe someone will encounter similar problem so i am posting my solution.

Take care!

Comment: Well, that is (*nearly*) the standard way to update nested properties. There wasn't enough context between the code you originally had issue with and the updated edit that included *some* of the `Update` component to connect the dots that the state you are updating there had anything to do with the original snippet.

Comment: Guess posting a question here helped me look at the problem from a different angle. If something was unclear - sorry for confusion. Will do my best to be more precise next time asking for support.

Comment: No worries, with practice we get better at asking better questions, providing an acceptable amount of context, answering questions, etc... Good luck.